# How to add specific attributes to JSF datatable header

Tags: datatable, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.2 and want to add some specific attributes to the datatable header row. The end result in HTML should look something like this.

```
<table>
<th my-attribute="myattributevalue"> Header Column </th>
....
```

Is this possible in JSF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`<f:passThroughAttribute/>`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/p/tld-summary.html) to set custom attributes. The `th` can be rendered by setting `rowHeader="true"` on an `<h:column/>`

```
    <h:dataTable>
          <h:column rowHeader="true">
               <h:outputText value="Header Column"/>
               <f:passThroughAttribute name="my-attribute" value="myattributevalue"/>
          </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using the f:passThroughAttribute and its  not working. I have included the following: "xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" and using it as mentioned here.<h:outputText value="Name" pt:my_attribute="myattributeValue"/>

Comment: Don't use the attribute version; use the tag-based version as I've specified here @Adwin