# how to add ID attribute to header of h:datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, myfaces, facet

here is a code snippet of datatable in myfaces.

```
<h:dataTable class="pretty" value="#{someValue}" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
         </f:facet>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="Outstanding"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:column>       
</h:dataTable>
```

This would produce html with

```
<th></th>
```

for the table. 
I am trying to set the id and header as below to the th tag:

```
<th id="value" headers="header value">
```

but not sure how to do it in myfaces f:facet as it only provides name to be set along with some other values. Any help to set the id and headers to the th tag would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: btw I tried setting id using : `<h:dataTable class="pretty" value="#{someValue}" >
    <h:column columnId="value" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
         </f:facet>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="Outstanding"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:column>       
</h:dataTable> `

Comment: What is the advantage to give id attribute to `f:facet` as you know facet are stored as a attribute ?

Comment: This is to provide the fix to WCAG issue: Success Criteria 1.3.1 Info and Relationships (A).  _Check 245: Data table with more than one row/column of headers does not use id and headers
attributes to identify cells.
Repair: Add id and headers attributes to table cells so they identify the cells that relate to the headers._     [http://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=245]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by creating a custom renderer which extends the:

```java
org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlTableRenderer
```

Modified the function to add the extra bit of attributes:

```java
protected void renderColumnHeaderCell(FacesContext facesContext, 
        ResponseWriter writer, UIComponent uiComponent, UIComponent facet,
        String headerStyleClass, int colspan) throws IOException
```

And then adding the config in the `faces-config.xml` to point to our class:

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Data</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Table</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>OurClass</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another way of doing without using `f:facet`. Here is a link to that
[How to add specific attributes to JSF datatable header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361546/how-to-add-specific-attributes-to-jsf-datatable-header?rq=1)

Comment: That feature is only available since JSF 2.2.

Comment: oh we are using Myfaces-2.0.2. I don't think it will work. Any other way of doing it ?